# rpc_timeout exception while inserting using cql2 or cql3

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a column family which structure is

```
CREATE TABLE practice (
  id text,
  name text,
  addr text,
  pin text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
) WITH
comment='' AND
caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
replicate_on_write='true' AND
compaction_strategy_class='SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' AND
compression_parameters:sstable_compression='SnappyCompressor';

CREATE INDEX idx_address ON practice (addr);
```

Initially i have made the column family using CQL 3.0.0. Then for creating the index i have used CQL 2.0.

Now when want to insert any data in the column family it always shows  a timeout exception.

```
INSERT INTO practice (id, name, addr,pin) VALUES ( '1','AB','kolkata','700052');
```

Request did not complete within rpc_timeout.

Please suggest me where i am getting wrong?

Comment: Did you check the log for errors?

Comment: yes i did check the log files. No relevant information. Same question i had posted in cassandra forum also. Please check that also http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/rpc-timeout-exception-while-inserting-td7584186.html

Answer (score 1):

As an answer on [the linked Cassandra forum question](http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/rpc-timeout-exception-while-inserting-td7584186.html) says, this might be because you mikxed CQL2 and CQL3. You should stick with one or the other.

Comment: that's being asked by me only. Anyways thanks for the response